# jQuery animation mouse event

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm creating a sample application where I need to change the color of a div as soon as user moves cursor away from it.

It's working but accurate, not sure where I'm going wrong.

See my sample application below.

http://jsfiddle.net/manishparab/3q1trzwk/

```
var cursorX = 0;
var cursorY = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".a").mouseover(function() {
        animateDiv();
        setInterval(function() {
            isCursorOnSquare('.a')
        }, 1);
    });
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    cursorX = e.pageX;
    cursorY = e.pageY;
});

function isCursorOnSquare(elem) {
    var pos, width, height;
    pos = $(elem).position();
    if ((Math.abs(pos.left - cursorX) <= 100 && Math.abs(pos.top - cursorY) <= 100)) {
        $(elem).css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
        $(elem).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
}

function makeNewPosition() {
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];    
}

function animateDiv() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition(); 
    var speed = 2000; 
    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function() {
        animateDiv();        
    });
}
```

Comment: what is not accurate?

Comment: Please check the JS fiddle... the overlap is not correct...even though mouse is outside the block color is red...which should not be case

Comment: so you want when the mouse is not in the div the color must be yellow and if its inside the div color must be red.. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In your code using .abs() the mouse event is also firing when the mouse is -100px to the left or top of the div.

You could also use mouseenter() to accomplish this,

```
$("div").mouseenter(function(){
    $("div").css("background-color", "red");
}).mouseleave(function(){
$("div").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'mouseenter' and 'mouseout'  events it will help.

```
$('#divID').on('mouseenter', function () {
  //your code
});

$('#divID').on('mouseout', function () {
  //your code
});
```